# Quicksort won't sort more than 50 elements

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort, off-by-one

Here's how I generate the numbers to be sorted.

```
vector<int> list;
for (i=0;i<50;i++) list.push_back(rand() %1000);
```

Here is my call in main

```
quickSort(list , 0, (list.size() -1 ));
```

here's the quicksort function

```
int pivot = left;
int temp = right;

if(left > right - 1)
    return;

while (left != right) {
    if (pivot == left){
        if (list[pivot] > list[right]) {
            //-------------------------
            std:swap(list, right, pivot);
            //-------------------------
            pivot = right;
            left++;
        }else{
            right--;
        }

    }else{
        if (list[pivot] < list[left]) {
            //-------------------------
              swap(list, left, pivot);
            //-------------------------
            pivot = left;
            right--;
        }else{
            left++;
        }
    }
}
quickSort(list, 0, right -1);
quickSort(list, right + 1, temp);
```

As the number of elements I'm sorting gets closer to about 50 the time it takes to sort get exponentially larger. I'm out of ideas. Anyone ever dealt with this before?

Comment: whats the prototype for quickSort?

Comment: `std::swap` doesn't take 3 arguments.

Comment: @Ken That's correct behaviour iff the element that ends up at `right` is the pivot.

Comment: Sure that it is exponential or only quadratic? Try other seeds. Next, I would try replacing std::swap by a plain-old manual swap.